Doubt in Potentiometre Resistance
so in a potentiometre, if we connect an external resistance in parallel to the cell, then why is resistance added like seris while calculating the current flowing through the cell and resistance ?
Bt- Battery
k1- Key
CD- potentiometre wire
e- cell
R- extrenal resistance which we include(used in calculating e)

my doubt is why is I given as e/(R+r)
like aren't they in parallel, then why seris equivalent resistance is calculated ?

Can you include a schematic? What is "the cell" in your system?

I was studying determination of internal resistance in a cell using potentiometre.

There is no potentiometer in your schematic. Can you give more context for your question? When you say "cell" do you mean an electrochemical cell (a "battery"), a photoelectric cell ("solar cell"), or something else? What do the different elements (E, V, J, and G) represent in your schematic? You can't expect us to read your mind --- you have to tell us what kind of devices you are asking about.

Are you sure the equation you quoted is meant to apply to the circuit you shared? It's a typical equation for a battery (electrochemical cell) with a resistor load, not for ... whatever it is ... shown in your schematic.

the potentiometre is a wire with a certain voltage drop per length, you can see the point marked J, this denotes the balancing length.

You seem unable to clarify: what ist V why does it not contribute to I, what is G it seems E is just  driving ? Now a new picture what are K where is r now, use some words!

i guess this diagram would be more clear

i wasn't really sure how to ask, sorry about that.


if we connect an external resistance in parallel to the cell, then why is resistance added like seris while calculating the current flowing through the cell and resistance ?

The confusing aspect (which you left out of the diagram in the initial version of your question, indicating you may not have realized its significance) is the "high resistance" HR. We assume that HR has such high resistance that almost no current flows through it. (It should be chosen to allow just enough current through to detect when the galvanometer is at its zero point, typically a matter of a few microamps).
(Further, as pointed out in Farcher's answer, when you adjust the potentiometer to find the balance point, you have also found the point where the current through the galvanometer actually goes to zero, not just approximately zero)
Therefore as far as finding the current through the cell, we have only the very simple circuit (I've included the cell's equivalant internal resistance in the diagram as r):

You've probably seen this circuit before, when learning about the internal resistance of an electrochemical cell. You should also be able to see why the internal resistance r and the external resistor R are treated as being in series.

The circuit you are investigating is shown below and you are going to compare potential differences across the battery, ie across nodes $A$ and $B$, $V_{\rm AB}= \dfrac{\mathcal E \,R}{r+R}$.

The rest of the circuit is used to make the comparison of potential differences.

At balance, zero reading on the galvanometer, the potential difference across $AB$ is equal to the potential difference across the wire $CJ$.
The potential difference across $CJ$ is proportional to the length of wire $CJ$ which is $ \ell_{\rm CJ}$,ie $\, V_{\rm CJ} \propto \ell_{\rm CJ}$
Thus at balance, $V_{\rm AB} = V_{\rm CJ} = k \,\ell_{\rm CJ}$ where $k$ is a constant which will be eliminated by taking at least two readings.
The experiment could be done with a high resistance voltmeter across $AB$.
